# Reduce the zoom of android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a `ScrollView`. it's a long page and i want to have a `Screenshot` from all the page so i have to reduce the zoom of emulator. How should i do that?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1" >


 <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">   

<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:stretchColumns="1">
.
.
.

</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

## SORRY

I know the code is not related to question, but stackoverflow compels me to write more about question. i think its AI not working well because my question is just the 2 first lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below. Use the scrollview and draw the same on canvas with the required height and width

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width , height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
v.draw(c);
return b;
}
```